# How to crop an element and keep the size adjusted

Tags: html, css

I have an element which I would like to crop x% of it from the right, and so the width will automatically decrease by half to fit the new content.

Currently I'm using this:

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width:180px;
}
i{
  color: yellow;
}
span i{
  position:relative;
  left: 50%;

}
span{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.1/css/all.min.css">
<div>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <span> 
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
  </span>

</div>
```

But as you can see when using it the `span` keeps it's original width and doesn't crop
[image]
Or using `clip-path`
[image]

so it creates an extra gap between the half star and the solid star before/after it.

---

I have tried using `transform: translateX(-x%);` on the container but it sabotages the entire layout and every element positioned after it gets a x% offset.

---

Is there a way to crop the element and so it's size?

---

**NOTE: the real element size is *dynamic*. I prefer a pure css solution that doesn't evolve using constants /JS**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit, after understanding the question, you may use width + overflow

If it is dynamic and can show up many times, you may use var() to update the value on the fly

examples

> **Why do i use em for sizing ?** - because **its size is about its own `font-size`** : here : `fa-2x` in your question , which `em` will match even if the class turns to be `fa-4x` .

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width:180px;
  margin:1em;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 3px)
}
i{
  color: yellow;
}
div i:last-of-type{
width: var(--size);
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.1/css/all.min.css">


<div style="--size: calc(1em * 0.3)">
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>30%
    
</div>
<div style="--size: calc(1em * 0.6)">
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>60%
</div>


<div style="--size: calc(1em * 0.7)">
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>70%
</div>
```

---

You may use clip-path, it will allow you to cut off a portion of the element . % can be used .

It also can allow you to cut it off with different shapes .

This will help you create your first clip-path https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

specification https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

examples

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width:180px;
  margin:1em;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 3px)
}
i{
  color: yellow;
}
div i:last-of-type{
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 60% 0, 60% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

/*cut half of its surface  , but differently*/
[title] i:last-of-type{
clip-path: polygon(0 40%, 100% 40%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
[class] i:last-of-type{
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 100%, 0% 100%);
}

[id] i:last-of-type{
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.1/css/all.min.css">
<div>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>60%
</div>

<div title="2.6">
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>60%
</div>

<div class>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>50%
</div>

<div id >
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>50%
</div>
```

Comment: it affects the layout after it. try to change `i:last-of-type` to `i:nth-of-type(2)`,  to see

Comment: @ATP ha!, did not noticed that. thks . BUT , why nth-of-type(2) ? any specific reasons you did not tell ?

Comment: to show you that every icon after it moves to the right. you can do see with `i:nth-of-type(1)` too

Comment: okay,so  you do want to reduce the size and hide what overflow ;) clip-path only hides part of it, but the element keeps its original size in the flow . I misunderstood what you meant by cropping ;)

Comment: I wrote it `>Is there a way to crop the element and so it's size?`

Comment: crop is what mislead most of us here :) . Answer updated

Comment: @ATP oki, so what's wrong this time ? We have no idea how the code can know about how much % is to be cropped ;) (you said elsewhere it could be 60%) ;)  Have a nice summer, its holliday time for me now.

Comment: Thanks! you too!, I didn't see your edit. can you explain the `(1em * x)` ? why it is 1em?

Comment: @ATP  1em is about the size of the of the <i class="fa..."> x is the percentage that you want it to be: 1 = 100% |  0.5=50% and so on  . it is just very basic math. mainly, **1em**  does the trick to start with. here an example where font-size is different https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VwXQegx .

Comment: That's very weird, I tried it before and it didn't work. maybe because it didn't have overflow hidden

Comment: The only problem with this solution, is that it works only for text elements. maybe in the feature there will be a comprehensive solution.

Comment: @ATP If the idea is to use an svg icone , you could do it this way : `<i class="fa-solid "><svg ...` and styling : `i.fa-solid svg {
  display:block;
  width:1em;
}` . i updated the codepen  so you can see

Comment: I got it, for mr this solution is enough. I mean in case someone will want to do this with more complex element in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the width of each star, which is 36px in this case. Then you can just set the width to 16px for the last star and add overflow hidden.

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width:180px;
}

i{
  color: yellow;
  width: 36px;
}

.half-star {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.1/css/all.min.css">
<div>
  <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star half-star"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: It's dynamic. it is only a demonstration

Comment: @ATP What do you mean by 'dynamic' , can you clarify _(inside the question so you may get more efficient answers)_ ? where does come from the value to crop ?

Comment: The icon size will be determined at run time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [clip](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_clip.asp) property and just for example do that
`clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);` it should split it in half

Comment: well use the `clip-path` property and the right element, here there is an image in the background but the blue shape is changing shapes. Thus with the right parameters you will be able to decrease it by 50%. Or maybe i didn't understood your problem ..

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`fa-star-half`](https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/star-half?s=solid)** as an alternative to custom styles. This will ensure dynamicity.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 180px;
}

i {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.1/css/all.min.css">

<div>
  <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star-half"></i>
</div>
```

**Solution w/o `fa-star-half`.**

I called your custom `span` with the customs styles `.custom`. This solution requires removing `justify-content: space-evenly` and uses a `calculated` `width` on your `span`'s that are not custom.

However, you still want the `.custom` span to be factored into this width. So you can set something like `span:not(.custom) { width: calc(100% / 3); }` Then, you will want to set `text-align: center;` to the non custom `spans`'s also.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 180px;
}

i {
  color: yellow;
}

span.custom i {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}

span.custom {
  overflow: hidden;
}

span:not(.custom) {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  outline: black 1px dotted;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.1/css/all.min.css">
<div>
  <span>
      <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
  </span>
  <span>
      <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
  </span>
  <span class="custom"> 
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to be able to crop 60% also, it is only a demonstration

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to make the star half, you could use `<i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>` instead of trying to crop it in half and then fit to the content.

Please let me know if I have misunderstood your question.

EDIT:
I would make a parent container for each star that is responsible for the width and height, and let the child base its width on the preferred percentage.

```css
  .star-row {
    display: flex;
    gap: 5px;
  }

  i {
    color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .last-star {
    width: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.1/css/all.min.css">

<div class="star-row">
  <div class="star-container">
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="star-container">
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star last-star"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You did understand, but I want to be able to crop 60% also, it is only a demonstration

Comment: Edited previous post. Please have a look.

Answer (score -1):

it's simple you just need to use negative for margin element.

`margin-right:-18px;`

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width:180px;
}
i{
  color: yellow;
}
span i{
  margin-right:-18px;
}
span{
  background:red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.1/css/all.min.css">
<div>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <span>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
  </span>

</div>
```

Comment: Please read the NOTE

Answer (score -1):

Using `clip-path` can be a practical solution for this case.

It's not size dependent, and you can use any value between 0-100% for the `--percentage` variable.

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width:180px;
}
i{
  color: yellow;
}
i:last-child{
  --percentage: 50%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, var(--percentage) 0, var(--percentage) 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.1/css/all.min.css">
<div>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
  </span>

</div>
```

If the last star bounding box is a concern, you should be able to achieve that by providing a width like this.

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 180px; 
  --star-count: 5;
  --star-width: calc(100% / var(--star-count));
  --last-star-crop: 1/2;
}
i{
  width: var(--star-width);
  color: yellow;
}
i:last-child{
  width: calc(var(--star-width) * var(--last-star-crop));
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.1/css/all.min.css">
<div>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-star"></i>
  </span>

</div>
```

Note: FontAwesome uses font-size to dictate icon sizing, due to that smaller container widths can cause distortion.

Comment: The bounding box of the third star is still full width. read the question

Comment: Generally, I would advise against it (the half star technically should have a full star size) your case might differ. See my edit